# python: change xml node value by a increase number

Tags: python, tags, numbers

I have a XML document "data.xml": 
I need to write python script which can replace all the value nodes with tag 'Num' with the new numbers and write it back to the disk.
the difference is that the new value is not string, but a series of continous increasing number, like 1000,1100,1200,1300...
I hav done research online, most code samples are string replace, not such variable replace. Anybody hav good idea? sample as follow:

before change:

`<Param><Num>123</Num></Param>
<Param><Num>123</Num></Param>
<Param><Num>123</Num></Param>`

after change:

`<Param><Num>1000</Num></Param>
<Param><Num>1100</Num></Param>
<Param><Num>1200</Num></Param>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question would be much easier to answer if it showed an example (you should show a small snippet of XML and then show what it should be transformed into).

Comment: any people hav reference or idea. since i have not find any suitable example online. thx! im python beginer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy to achieve with the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library

```
from lxml import  objectify

class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, tree, counter_start, counter_interval):
        self.tree = tree
        self.root = tree.getroot()
        self.counter_start = counter_start
        self.counter_interval = counter_interval

    def parse(self):
        counter = self.counter_start
        # for loop to iter voltage items
        # using counter += counter_interval to set the value for example
        # save the tree within the parser class or in the handle function


def handle(file):
    f = open(file)
    tree = objectify.parse(f)
    parser = Parser(tree, 1000, 100)
    parser.parse()
    f.close()

handle("/Desktop/bar.XML")
```

Comment: excuse, do u hav any more simple and direct idea. i tried ur method, but it need to install lib and my python is 2.6

Comment: @TJLD22: `lxml` installs fine on Python 2.6. How have you tried installing it.

Comment: yes, tried already, then it say DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. i download another 32&64 bit file, but problem still exist